# How to play video from remote URL in android?

Tags: android

I am New to android my intention is to play video using Http.

But i am getting  "Http Request Failed 404" Exception when iam trying to run my application in  emulator.
can any one know this error?

plz help me Thanks in advance.

Comment: helo try to run ur code in real device surely you can run

Answer (score 0):

404 normally means the URL cannot be found.

What is the exact URL & have you tried to play that URL in software like **mplayer** or **VLC**?

Answer (score 0):

404 error means it can not find the video file on the URL that you provided.
perhaps you have given a wrong URL?